# Comparing Values in a Single Dictionary - Python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, compare

Say we have a dictionary that contains a list of words:

```
temp = {"1": "hello", "2": "goodbye", "3": "hello", "4": "goodbye", "5": "hi"}
```

I need help figuring out how to compare the values of each key. I understand I need to iterate through each but I can't figure out how to compare values of "1" to "2", and so on.

Output should be:

`"1" == "3"
"2" == "4"
"5" ==`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with *compare*, I do not see any comparisons.

Comment: What ? it's not same as duplicate question

Comment: @Arman, Correct: dict['1'] == dict[2'], but then dict['1'] == dict['3'], and same for the other ones. I understand but I just put it up there as an example.

Comment: @MartijnPieters How exactly are those duplicates?

Comment: @schwobaseggl: `combinations(dict, 2)` will produce the desired key-pairs. This is basically a problem on how to produce those pairings.

Comment: `[(a, b) for a, b in combinations(dict, 2) if dict[a] == dict[b]]` will produce all key pairs where the values are equal.

Comment: @MartijnPieters But that exponential approach seems far from optimal for this exact problem.

Comment: @schwobaseggl: reopened; my initial reading of the question was 'how do I generate pairs so I can test for equality'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following. Collect all keys for each in `dict` (or [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)) of `lists`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

temp = {"1": "hello", "2": "goodbye", "3": "hello", "4": "goodbye", "5": "hi"}
d = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in temp.items():
    d[v].append(k)

for k in d:
    print ' = '.join(repr(v) for v in d[k])  # repr only necessary to display quotes
    # print ' = '.join(d[k])
'5'
'1' = '3'
'2' = '4'
```

Comment: list in defaultdict(list) gave me a TypeError, unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: Code works here.  Are there any lists as values in your original `dict`?

Comment: Yes, they are a list of words

Comment: 'd[v].append(k)' TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' is the error

Comment: Then you should put that in the question.  You can do:  `d[tuple(v)].append(k)` though

Comment: You, sir, are a genius. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `defaultdict` from the `collections` module to essentially invert the dict (i.e. make it of type old value -> list of old keys that pointed to it). This can be achieved as below:

```
from collections import defaultdict
inverted_dict = defaultdict(list)
for k,v in temp.items():
    inverted_dict[v].append(k)
```

Then each value in the old dict shows up as a key in the new dict and you can print the "equal" keys out by iterating over `inverted_dict` and printing the list, eg:

```
for k,v in inverted_dict.items():
    print v
```